# Tool or process to automatically snap endpoints of polylines within given proximity using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, snapping

I created a network of polylines that were all supposed to be connected.

However, I just realized that many of the endpoints of the lines aren't connected, but are very close.

I think there should be a tool to snap the endpoints of the polylines if they are very close to each other, but I can't seem to find it.

Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Comment: The Snapper and AnchoredSnapper transformers in the Data Interoperability Extension will also do this.

Comment: I could not locate the two functions you mentioned. I am working with ArcGIS 10.3.1. Besides, why do they keep changing the location of certain functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The direction of the answer would depend on the license level of your ArcMap. ArcInfo does have this capability built in. Even Editor has some tools to accomplish this task. However with ArcView level you would need to depend on other tools to do this. Not sure if it has changed in 10. I have ArcMap editor 10 and the **snap** command

> **Summary**
>
> Moves points or vertices to coincide exactly with the vertices, edges, or end points of other features. Snapping rules can be specified to control whether the input vertices are snapped to the nearest vertex, edge, or endpoint within a specified distance.

is what I would use. If you need other tools I think there are some free tools in et-geotools that will do it.

Comment: How can this work, given that it asks for a reference shapefile? If I have a shapefile of disconnected lines and want to connect them, I would do it based on an XY tolerance (or buffer), not on a list of positions stored in another shapefile (that I don't have). So, if my interpretation of the OP is correct, this solution does not work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: exerpt from the ESRI Help for SNAP - In the Snap Environment parameter, multiple snap rules can be designated using the "same layer" or feature class with a different type (END | VERTEX | EDGE).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the geoprocessing "Integrate" tool which clusters vertices in the same way that topology validate does (without the need of creating a topology).

At ArcGIS 10.0 there is a new tool called "Snap" in the Editing toolbox.  The tool snaps the feature's vertices from 1 layer to the edge, vertex, endpoint of another feature.  See link below.

[Desktop Help - Snap (Editing) Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Snap/001v00000007000000/)

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the distance identified as "close" there are tools. If you have at least an ArcEditor License for ArcGIS Desktop then you could create a Topology on the data. Once done during validation process the lines will move the distance of the cluster tolerance to snap to each other. By default the cluster tolerance is .001 m which is 10 times the default resolution of your data.

If this automatic process does not do all of these it will identify where the errors are, in ArcMap there is an Error Inspector which will allow you to extend bulk lines so that it can then connect where possible. this will then enable you to have as many automated as possible.

Hope this helps,
CDB

Answer (score 4):

You can create a geometric network from those polylines and during the creation wizard you can enable feature snapping:

1. Create geodatabase
2. Create feature dataset
3. Import your polylines
4. Right-click on the feature dataset
5. New -> Geometric Network
6. Select your feature class
7. When asked if the features are to be snapped, click yes and define a snapping tolerance
8. Click through the rest of the wizard

The wizard will move your lines to match the endpoint of other lines in that feature class within the given snapping distance. HTH