# Match polylines up to polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, snapping, arcgis-9.2, spatial-adjustment

I'm trying to **match** **polyline** layer features up to **polygon edges** in a different layer **quickly**.
I have a **huge extent** of polygons (river) and separate lines (bank features) that I need to get to follow/match the polygon outlines.

Spatial adjustment not working, reshape/modify features will be too time-consuming with snapping each vertex...

Is there a quicker easier way? I have ArcMap 9.2.

Comment: You could try a nearest Join, however, we would be able to give you more specific help if you tell us what software you are using.

Comment: Thanks for adding the software.  Do you want to keep the polyline geometry? Or do you just need its attributes?  i.e. do you just want the polyline attributes assigned to the polygon features?

Comment: Unfortunately, need to keep it as a separate polyline feature complete with attributes... rather than just attach attributes to polygon...

Comment: Try a spatial join http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111011/53268

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to just find out distances... I want to move the polyline to match the polygon outline..

Comment: There are several questions on this topic here, but unfortunately many of them rely on tools that I think were introduced after your version of Arc - particularly Snap and possibly Align to Shape. You might check to see if either are available, or review the following questions/answers: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122934/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141361/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3428/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141720/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98469/

Comment: Do note that Integrate will alter both layers, and trace/reshape is a shortcut to snapping each vertex (and is definitely available at your level, though still time consuming).

Answer (score 2):

To trace the lines onto polygons, try using the [Integrate](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=1522&pid=1515&topicname=Integrate_(Data_Management)) tool:

> Compares features and makes any lines, points, or vertices within a
>   certain distance range identical or coincident.

To match the attributes of the polygons to the lines, you can use the spatial join by @wittich or other similar methods described in [Match features that are spatially similar with ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153115/match-features-that-are-spatially-similar-with-arcgis).

Since you're on 9.2, unfortunately you won't have the [Conflation toolset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-conflation-toolset.htm).

Comment: Note that Integrate will move/modify *both* layers, so if you're only wanting to adjust one layer to match another, it isn't suitable.